# javascript overlay not covering full page when div expands the page height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overlay

I realize there's already been several questions like this, but I think my case is a little different.
I have an div that I am absolutely positioning and floating on top of the page, and I'm setting an overlay behind it to grey out the rest of the page.  I have it working okay until you scroll up and down the page.

The problem is, when the div appears, it is still populating with ajax data.  So the height and width of the bg overlay has already been set, but once all the data loads into the floating div, it sometimes pushing the page down so the height increases.  So, I can't calculate the height and width of the window or document because the floating div might not be fully loaded yet, and once it does, it pushes the screen down further, causing the bg overlay to not cover the whole page.

So for example, in the code it's going something like:

```
loadBoxContent = function(){
..DO AJAX HERE..
..PUT CONTENT INTO FLOATING DIV..
$('#floatDiv').show()
$('#darkOverlay').height($(window).height());

}
```

I verified this by adding an alert, so that by the time I've clicked the alert, the bg overlay was able to calculate the true page size, and it looks fine.
Sorry, if this sounds confusing but hopefully you get what I'm trying to achieve.  I'm assuming this isn't too difficult, but I haven't been able to figure it out.
Any help would be appreciated, I'm using jquery.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Overlay ;)

** update, setting position of all corners to 0 instead of using width/height 100% **

```
$("<div/>")
 .css({
    position:"fixed", // ze trick 
    background:"#000",
    opacity:.5,
    top:0,
    bottom: 0,
    left:0,
    right: 0,
    zIndex: 2999 // everything you want on top, gets higher z-index
  })
 .appendTo("body");
```

Or put the above css settings in a css stylesheet (opacity needs cross browser hacks).

```
$("#dark-overlay").show();
```

Comment: I It does not work when your inner div size is more than screen size.

Comment: @Farzin Yes it does, `fixed` positioning is relative to the viewport, not the page so when you start scrolling, the whole viewport remains covered.

Comment: Copy the code, paste it in your browser console on this site (jQuery present) and see it work ;)

Comment: I was missing the position: fixed piece!  Thanks I knew it had to be something relatively straightforward.

Comment: Note: position:fixed is disabled in (most?) mobile browsers, but if using modals in mobile sites is a good thing...

Comment: Another note: IE5/6 do not support position:fixed, a fallback is to use position:absolute instead, still set width/height to 100% and (re)position the overlay on the onscroll event rather than calculating width/height of viewport. But tbh. don't support IE6 and lower...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution :

[JQuery Show Loading Plugin](http://contextllc.com/dev_tools/jQuery/showLoading/latest/jquery.showLoading.example.html)

Don't try to invent the wheel !!!

Here is a demo :

[Loading Demo](http://contextllc.com/dev_tools/jQuery/showLoading/latest/jquery.showLoading.example.html)

Now you just need to create a main container div for your page and just ask this simple plugin to do it for you.

Maybe you want to read the plugin source and find how it works...

Comment: The one issue is that the callback function which populates the data into the floating div is the same one that calculates the height and width of the bg overlay.  So I think the floating div is still expanding (and thus expanding the height of the page) while the bg overlay height is being calculated.

Comment: using this jQuery plugin you don't need to set size of your floating div manually. jQuery plugin will do it for you. you just need to call your ajax method and every thing about floating div will be controlled by this jQuery library.